# Toggling a group of checkboxes from a master checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox

I have the following JS which is actually working and checks all my boxes if the one of the top is checked (currently works) therefore I am unable to UNCHECK them by repeating the same process (unchecking the first box is not uncheckable)

I have the following code which actually call my function each time the checkbox is unchecked or checked:

```
function refresh_checkbox_list(){
    // document.getElementById('gdr_select_users').setAttribute("checked");

    (function() {
    var aa = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
    for (var i = 0; i < aa.length; i++){
        aa[i].checked = true;
    }
})()
}

<input type="checkbox" name="gdr_select_all_users" id="gdr_select_all_users" onchange="refresh_checkbox_list()">
<input type="checkbox" name="gdr_select_users" id="gdr_select_users">
```

Just to say: I am a truly noob of JavaScript, I know how I would process it in PHP so it does check and uncheck, but I don't know how does "if" statements work in JS, this is my actual problem..

I was thinking about an if statement that checks if my 1st box is checked then check all others boxes, then another statement which do the exact reverse. Right?

I must admit that I have also found that JS on this website (an user which had a similar case)

Comment: Seems like you are looking for a radio button. There is no javascript required, that can be done with pure html.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply! I have tried with a radio button but the fact is that you can't uncheck a radio button if there is only one. What I mean is that for this to work you need at least 2 radio buttons, I would have only one in this case wich would be on the top, not in my user list (these would be checkboxes to check to specific user and I know how to do it so there is not problem on this side). and as I have to check in real time for my user input I can't use HTML nor PHP, I must use both PHP & Javascript. But thanks anyway for your idea! :)

Comment: Just use `<input value="none" checked />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `true` use the checked state of `#gdr_select_all_users`.

Also need to exclude `#gdr_select_all_users` from the loop. Can use `not()` in the query selector or better yet apply a common class to the user checkboxes

```js
function refresh_checkbox_list(){
    // get checked state of the "check all" box 
    let allChecked = document.getElementById('gdr_select_all_users').checked;
    (function() {
    var aa = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:not(#gdr_select_all_users)");
    for (var i = 0; i < aa.length; i++){
        // set other checkboxes to same state as the "check all"
        aa[i].checked = allChecked;
    }
})()
}
```

```html
Check all:<input type="checkbox" name="gdr_select_all_users" id="gdr_select_all_users" onchange="refresh_checkbox_list()">

<br>
User 1<input type="checkbox" name="gdr_select_users_1" >
<br>
User 2<input type="checkbox" name="gdr_select_users_2" >
```

Comment: Oh! It works VERY fine! Thank you very much for your help ! And I am very sorry again for asking such a stupid question..

By the way, I found some documentation on how conditions works but I did not understand well, so if I want to check for a statement it would be like

"var mystatement = <my condition> == <mycondition> ;

is it correct? thank you anyway for all of your help!

Comment: Crap... I tried to understand your code and I understand now how stupid I was, Instead of just getting the value of my top checkbox and then apply it to the others checkboxes, what I did was checking my top checkbox then setting a custom value "checked" to the other checkboxes, this way I could not remove it... Thanks !

EDIT -- also I didnt know I had to exclude the first checkbox (on the top) when applying the value, wich seems logic too.